# Can geoserver handle normal get request?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers, url

I am relatively  new to the geoserver, backend - frontend GIS architecture. I know how to generate a WFS with geoserver from my PostGIS database and retrieve this data in my openlayers frontend.

However, I still would like to know how I can handle the case of a mobile app, sending attributes via an URL with gps coordinates etc. to the postGIS database through Geoserver. The app generating the URL already exists. I just would like to know if Geoserver can handle a basic get request from this URL to send the data to the database. This would happen every 30 sec or so.

EDIT: 
It is not a WFS which is generated by the app. so i have to create the PostGIS geometry within Geoserver with the available coordinate values from the URL

Comment: would this be a WFS request or just a random get request?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: It sounds like you want a WFS-T. The app/client isn't a WFS it sends data to the WFS server...